# Have a question about Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra

Explain why there cannot be a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ for which $T(1,1)=(2,3)$ and $T(3,3)=(1,4)$.

I have no clue how to start this problem. Wouldn't $T(4,4)=4T(1,1)=4(2,3)=(8,12)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(6,9)=3(2,3)=3T(1,1)\not=T(3,3)=(1,4)$

Comment: oh, duh. Thanks! :)