# Finding an unknown linear transformation given that $T(1,1)=(1,0,2)$ and $T(2,3) = (1,-1,4)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation such that $T(1,1)=(1,0,2)$ and $T(2,3) = (1,-1,4)$.

Does such a linear transformation exist?

So far I've worked out that it cannot exist, as the first entry for $T(1,1)$ is 1, 
whereas the first entry for $T(2,3)$ is 1, which can only be obtained through 3-2, or half of 2.

Is there any way of presenting this formally?

Comment: You can have a look at some older questions asking whether a linear transformation given by similar conditions exists and how to find it. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996217/find-a-matrix-transformation-mapping-1-1-1-0-1-0-1-0-2-to-1-1-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280791/suppose-t-is-a-linear-transformation-such-that-t1-1-1-0-1-2-t1-0-1-1-1-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280735/have-a-question-about-linear-transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that your reason works. If a linear transformation exists, it should be a 2 by 3 matrix. Let this matrix have the entries $a$ and $b$ on the first row, $c$ and $d$ on the second and $e$ and $f$ on the third.
Performing matrix multiplication on <1,1> and <2,3> to get <1,0,2> and <1,-1,4> gives the following systems of equations to solve: $a+b=1$ with $2a+3b=1$, and $c+d=0$ with $2c+3d=-1$  lastly $e+f=2$ with $2e+3f=4$ These systems produce unique values for the matrix' entries. Sorry for my poor formatting

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\{(1,1),(2,3)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Great hint .. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Spoiler Warning: Full Solution**

We can write this as a matrix vector equation $${\bf T}\left[\begin{array}{rr}1&2\\1&3\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1&1\\
0&-1\\
2&4
\end{array}\right]$$

Since Arpit mentioned in the hint, $\{(1,1),(2,3)\}$ spans a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, why the matrix must be invertible. Now if we multiply each side to the right with $\left[\begin{array}{rr}1&2\\1&3\end{array}\right]^{-1}$:

$${\bf T} = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1&1\\
0&-1\\
2&4
\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{rr}1&2\\1&3\end{array}\right]^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}
2&-1\\
1&-1\\
2&0
\end{array}\right]$$
Now what remains is to confirm that the first equation is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A linear transformation $T: V \to W$ is uniquely determined by how it acts on the elements of a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple method to solve the problem described in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" and "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)."
Consider the formula
$$
\vec{T}(\vec{p}) = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            0   & \vec{x} & \vec{y} \\
            p_1 & a_1     & b_1     \\
            p_2 & a_2     & b_2     \\
        \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
        \begin{pmatrix}
            a_1 & b_1 \\
            a_2 & b_2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
},
$$
where $\vec{T}$ is linear transformation acting on arbitrary point $\vec{p}$. $\vec{T}$ has the property
$$
\vec{T}(\vec{a}) = \vec{x};\quad
\vec{T}(\vec{b}) = \vec{y}.
$$
Indices designate components of the corresponding vector.

Let's consider your case.
We need such $\vec{T}$ that
$$
\vec{T}: \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
         \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix};~
\vec{T}: \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 3\end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
         \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\ 4\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now I plug them into the general expression 
$$
\vec{T}(\vec{p}) =
(-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & (1,0,2)^T & (1,-1,4)^T\\
        \begin{matrix}
            p_{1} \\
            p_{2}
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}1\\ 1\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}2\\ 3\end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}1\\ 1\end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}2\\ 3\end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Doing determinants I get
$$
\vec{T}(\vec{p})
=   \left[
   3\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix} -
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\ 4\end{pmatrix}
\right] p_1 -
  \left[
   2\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix} -
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\ 4\end{pmatrix}
\right] p_2
$$
or simplified
$$
\vec{T}(\vec{p}) =
    \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} p_1 + 
    \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} p_2. 
$$
Of course, you can write that in a vector form
$$
\vec{T}(\vec{p}) =
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        2 &-1 \\
        1 &-1 \\
        2 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix} p_1 \\ p_2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now you can easily check
$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        2 &-1 \\
        1 &-1 \\
        2 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix};~
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        2 &-1 \\
        1 &-1 \\
        2 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix} 
    \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 3\end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{pmatrix}1\\ -1\\ 4\end{pmatrix}.
$$

For more details on the methods used, you can always refer to "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" and "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)". The latter contains many problems similar to this one as explained by the authors of the method presented.