# Find a linear transformation that $T((1,-1, 1))=(1, 0)$ and $T((1,1, 1))=(0, 1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is it possible to find a linear transformation
$T\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ only knowing this:  $T((1,-1, 1))=(1, 0)$ and  $T((1,1, 1))=(0, 1)$ ?

Comment: Yes, but $T$ is not unique.

Comment: And how do I do that? :)

Comment: Have you ever solved a similar exercise? See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454523/finding-an-unknown-linear-transformation-given-that-t1-1-1-0-2-and-t2-3?rq=1

Comment: I was thinking on finding a vector that is linearly independent to (1, 1, 1) a (1, -1, 1) in order to have an $R^3$ basis. Then, I would assign a value to this new vector by T. I now I would have a linear transformation determinated by the value of a basis.  Thank you for the examples, I'm going to check them

Comment: You are on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such transformation is defined by 6 paramaters $a,b,c,d,e,f$ which obey:
$$
a-b+c=1\\
d-e+f=0\\
a+b+c=0\\
d+e+f=1
$$ There are 4 equations for 6 unknowns, so we can, for example, solve it f0r $a,b,d,e$:
$$
a=\frac12-c\\
b=-\frac12\\
d=\frac12-f\\
e=\frac12
$$
Thus $c,f$ are left as free parameters. The transformation
$$T(x,y,z)=(v,w)$$ is then defined by:
$$
v=(\frac12-c)x -\frac12y+cz\\
w=(\frac12-f)x+\frac12y+fz
$$

Comment: Thank you so much